# Java 8 epoch-millis time stamp to formatted date, how?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

Before Java-8 I got accustomed to always keep anything date/time related as milliseconds since Epoch and only ever deal with human readable dates/times on the way out, i.e. in a UI or a log file, or when parsing user generated input.

I think this is still safe with Java-8, and now I am looking for the most concise way to get a formatted date out of a milliseconds time stamp. I tried

```
df = Dateformatter.ofPattern("...pattern...");
df.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp))
```

but it bombs out with `Unsupported field: YearOfEra` in `Instant.getLong(...)` which I half understand. Now what to use instead of `Instant`?

`LocalDateTime.ofEpoch(Instant, ZoneId)` seems wrong, since I don't care to have local time. I just want to see the local time zone when applying the formatter. Internally it should be just the `Instant`.

The same goes for `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant, ZoneId)`, I thought to apply the `ZoneId` only when formatting. But I notice that the `DateTimeFormatter` does not itself deal anymore with time zones, it seems, so I reckon I need to use one of the above.

Which one is preferred and why? Or should I use yet another way to format an epoch-millis time stamp as a date/time with time zone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `Instant` does not contain any information about the time-zone, and unlike in other places, the default time-zone is not automatically used. As such, the formatter cannot figure out what the year is, hence the error message.

Thus, to format the instant, you must add the time-zone. This can be directly added to the formatter using [`withZone(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-) - there is no need to manually convert to `ZonedDateTime` *:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("...pattern...").withZone(zone);
df.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp))
```

* regrettably, in early Java 8 versions, the `DateTimeformatter.withZone(ZoneId)` method did not work, however this has now been fixed, so if the code above doesn't work, upgrade to the latest Java 8 patch release.

Edit: Just to add that `Instant` is the right class to use when you want to store an instant in time without any other context.

Answer (score 7):

The error you have when formatting an `Instant` using a formatter built with a year or other fields is expected; an `Instant` does not know which year or month or day it is, it only knows how much milliseconds have elapsed since the Epoch. For the same instant, it could be 2 different days on 2 different places of the Earth.

So you need to add a time zone information if you want to print the day. With an `Instant`, you can call [`atZone(zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to combine it with a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) in order to form a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). This is very much like an instant, only that it has a time zone information. If you want to use the system time zone (the one of the running VM), you can get it with [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--).

To print it, you can use the two built-in formatter [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) or [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME). The difference between the two is that the zoned date time formatter will add the zone id to the output.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))));
```

when run on my machine, which has a system time zone of `"Europe/Paris"`, you'll get:

```
2016-07-31T18:58:54.108+02:00
2016-07-31T09:58:54.108-07:00
```

You can of course build your own formatter if those one do not suit you, using [`ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) or the builder [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is somewhat confusing, especially when compared with it's predecessor Joda DateTime.

The most confusing thing is that the documentation for LocalDateTime says that it is "A date-time without a time-zone", and yet LocalDateTime.ofInstant method takes both an instant and a timezone as parameters.

That said, I think that you can achieve what you want by using Instant and LocalDateTime.ofInstant by using the UTC timezone.

```
public LocalDateTime millisToDateTime(long millis) {
  return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis), ZoneId.of("Z");
}
```